# synchronizing separate folders when new documents are added

Tags: document-library, document

I would like the documents in one folder on a sharepoint page to contain the same documents as that of another page of the same site. So when one page has updated information it synchronizes with the other.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need you have a single document library in a site.
When a new item is added in that document library you need the document to be copied to another folder within the same doc. library don't you?

If this is the case add an event receiver to the document library with this code:

```
public class CustomEventReceiver: SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        item.File.CopyTo(item.ParentList.RootFolder.Name + "/Dest Folder Path/" + item.File.Name, true);
    }
}
```

Regards